# Rendering boxplots based on SelectiveInput R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to render some boxplots in R shiny through selectiveinput. I have my options, but when I run the app it just says cant find object and wont render. Here is my ui code, plotoutput is "boxplot":

```
selectInput(inputId = "Input3", "Boxplot:", 
            choices = c(label = NULL,
                        'Gunning Fog Index'= 'gfi',
                        'Percentage of hard words'= 'pohw',
                        'Flesch Readability Ease' = 'flesch',
                        'Automated Readability Index' = 'ari',
                        'Percentage of first person pronouns' = 'pofpp',
                        'Percentage of third person pronouns' = 'potpp')),
```

Here is my server code:

```
output$boxplot <- renderPlot({
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
# generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
boxplot(get(input$Input3), Flesch_fake, ylim = c(-20, 60), col = "red", main="Flesch Reading Ease - Fake")
})
```

If I try to use $flesch after Input3 in the renderPlot function, it says that the operator is invalid for atomic vectors. How can I get through this and just simply render a boxplot through SelectiveInput? The app itself works it just doesn't render the boxplots.

Comment: What is `Flesh_fake`? a column of dataframe `flesch`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Comment: Flesch_fake consists basically just of numbers...Flesch_fake = c(17.26,5.35,26.64,.... and so on .... and I have a boxplot made from these numbers, and want to assign it to an option in the selectinput so I can display my boxplot.

Comment: Sorry, Daniel, but your sample is not reproducible. With your instructions I can mock `Flesch_fake` but what are `gfi`, `pohw`, ...? I can only guess that these are data frames or lists because that is the only way for `get(input$Input3)$flesch` to make sense. Could you shed more light on this?

Comment: theyre just another lists just like Flesch_fake....its the same over and over again just different numbers. I have boxplots for each option just need to bind this boxplot to an option.